# My rsyslog.conf action doesn't trigger a Shell Execute

Tags: rsyslog

I'm using version 4.6.2 of rsyslog and have the following lines in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
$template InputToScript,"/home/user/%msg%"
if $msg contains "abcdefg" then ^touch;InputToScript
```

I did a `kill -1 <pid>` where `<pid>` is the PID for `rsyslogd`

Then I typed

```
logger "xxxabcdefgyyy"
```

I didn't see a file `/home/user/xxxabcdefgyyy` created.

Did I leave something out?

Comment: Does your configuration parse correctly?  You can always do the following to check:  rsyslogd -d -N 1

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this issue when the logfile was truncated from **logrotate** per https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/721 .

Turns out there is an option to **imfile** for handling truncation -- **reopenOnTruncate** -- otherwise logging will not continue until the truncated file reaches its original size

e.g.

```
input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/secure"
      Tag="secure-testing"
      Ruleset="secure_ruleset_testing"
      reopenOnTruncate="on")
```

You can also enable the **rsyslog debug output** per https://www.rsyslog.com/how-to-use-debug-on-demand/ --

```
export RSYSLOG_DEBUG="DebugOnDemand NoStdOut"
export RSYSLOG_DEBUGLOG=/somepath/example.log
/etc/rc.d/init.d/rsyslog stop
rsyslogd -n
```

In a separate session window run:

```
kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/rsyslogd.pid`
```

(ensure the pid file exists or just get it using the process list). Debug logging will show up in the specified file.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to state the full path of `touch` as a subshell is opened by rsyslog. So the code should be

`if $msg contains "abcdefg" then ^/usr/bin/touch;InputToScript`